# Animate UIView position on tableview scroll and again tableview drag

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I have a list of items which a header menu at the top.

When the user scrolls up the menu should scroll off screen also and when they return to the top of the list the menu should be visible.

In much the same way as a `tableViewHeader` behaves.

However, should the header be off screen and the user ends a drag down on the list, this header view should animate down from the top. If the user then ends a drag up on the list, the header should animate back off screen.

I have achieved the first part of this below, however am struggling to achieve the animation effect.

I had considered using 2 views for the menu, one that scrolls and one that animates it's position, however this feels off, I'm sure there must be a better way without duplicating views.

```swift
class TableViewScene: UIViewController {

  let data = Array(0...99)

  var headerViewOneTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
  var tableViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  lazy var headerViewOne: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .purple
    return view
  }()

  lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let view = UITableView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.delegate = self
    view.dataSource = self
    view.tableFooterView = .init()
    view.refreshControl = .init()
    return view
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    headerViewOneTopConstraint = headerViewOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
    tableViewTopConstraint = tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 184)

    [headerViewOne, tableView].forEach(view.addSubview)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      headerViewOneTopConstraint,
      headerViewOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      headerViewOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      headerViewOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 184),

      tableViewTopConstraint,
      tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    ])
  }
}

extension TableViewScene: UITableViewDelegate {
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    headerViewOneTopConstraint.constant = max(-184, min(0, -offsetY))
    tableViewTopConstraint.constant = 184 - max(0, offsetY)
  }
}
```

I had also tried adding this to the view

```swift
  func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)

    if translation.y > 0 {
      headerViewOne.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: 184)
    } else if translation.y < 0 {
      headerViewOne.transform = .identity
    }
  }
```

This does not work and instead just renders a black space the view used to fill on scroll to the top.

Comment: What kind of animation effect are you going for? What don't you like about your scrollViewDidScroll implementation?

Comment: `scrollViewDidScroll` works perfect, I'm very happy with that, however I am not able to `headerViewOne` back into and out of view when the user is for example half way down the table. `headerViewOne` is a "quick menu" and they should be able to view it at the top of the list or at any point in the list by dragging down

Comment: In terms of animation, just a simple sliding down and back up is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what you are looking for but this might work for you. In this implementation when the user drags up the header will hide and when the user drags down the header will show. This is true regardless of the scroll position.

I made a change to one of your constraints so that the top of the tableView is pinned to the bottom of the header:

```
    tableViewTopConstraint = tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerViewOne.bottomAnchor)
```

I'm also tracking the state of the header like so:

```
enum HeaderState {
    case hidden
    case revealed
    case hiding
    case revealing
}

var headerState: HeaderState = .revealed
```

Now for the scrolling logic. If the scroll position is near the top then we want to manually show/hide the header. However, if the scroll position is near the bottom or center then we want to animate the show/hide functionality.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 184 {
        if translation.y > 0 && headerState != .revealed && headerState != .revealing {
            headerViewOneTopConstraint.constant = max(-184, min(0, -scrollView.contentOffset.y))
        } else if translation.y < 0 {
            headerViewOneTopConstraint.constant = max(-184, min(0, -scrollView.contentOffset.y))
        }
        return
    }

    if translation.y > 0 && headerState == .hidden {

        self.headerState = .revealing
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.headerViewOneTopConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.headerState = .revealed
        })

    } else if translation.y < 0 && headerState == .revealed {

        self.headerState = .hiding
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.headerViewOneTopConstraint.constant = -184
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.headerState = .hidden
        })
    }
}
```

Give this a shot and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: ah yes that it perfect! Thank you so much very, very helpful